# Typescript - inherit return type from the argument property when argument is union

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a type which is a union of generic interface with 2 generic types. One of which is an enum and the other is different for each enum value.

When calling the function TS correctly recognise data type based on the enum value inside the function call but don't understand that the return value should be the same type as one of the properties of that object

code:

```js
interface Base<D = any, T = string> {
  data: D;
  type: T;
}

enum BaseTypes {
  foo,
  bar,
  boo,
}

type BaseSet = Base<number, BaseTypes.foo> | Base<string, BaseTypes.bar> | Base<{d: number}, BaseType.boo>;

function processData(payload: BaseSet): typeof payload.data {
  return payload.data;
}

// a type should be number
// but it's number | string
const a = processData({ data: 1, type: BaseTypes.foo });
```

My understanding is that the type of `a` should be inherited from the payload data type which in this case should be `string`. My two questions are:

- Why is it not working?
- How can i make it work?

Comment: The `payload` is not generic to the return type is `Base<D = any, T = string>.data: string | number`.  We can fix this by making the function generic.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem: Function is not Generic

The `processData` function is not a generic function.  It accepts an object argument which is either of the two `BaseSet` types.

It's return is typed as `typeof payload.data`.  The critical distinction is: *what is the type of `payload`?*  In this version, the type of `payload` is the union type `BaseSet` and thus the return type `typeof payload.data` is the union of all `data` types in `BaseSet`.

This is because we set the type for `payload` as `BaseSet` when we do `processData(payload: BaseSet)`.  If we have more specific information about the type of that `payload` variable, that information gets lost.  In order to preserve a more specific type for `payload` we need to use generics.

#### Solution: Generic Function

We can make `processData` a generic function and say that the type of the return depends on the type of the arguments that it was called with.  Here I am using the generic `D` to refer to the type of the `data` property.

```
function processData<D>(payload: BaseSet & {data: D}): D {
  return payload.data;
}
```

We say that the `payload` must have type `{data: D}` and also be a valid `BaseSet`.  This enforces the pairings but also allows typescript to infer a more specific version type for the `data`.  We then say that this specific type will be our return type.

Testing it out, we get the correct return types and also an error if the `data` and `type` don't match.

```
const a = processData({ data: 1, type: BaseTypes.foo }); // number
const b = processData({ data: "hahaha", type: BaseTypes.foo }); // error
const c = processData({ data: "hahaha", type: BaseTypes.bar }); // string
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Wzy8Rm)

There are multiple ways to define the generic function.  Is the generic the `data` type or the entire `payload` type?  Should we apply any constraints to `D` or is the `& BaseSet` enough?  Interestingly, this version gives me the literal strings and numbers as the return type.

```
function processData<D extends BaseSet['data']>(payload: BaseSet & {data: D}): D {
  return payload.data;
}
```

```
const a = processData({ data: 1, type: BaseTypes.foo }); // 1
const b = processData({ data: "hahaha", type: BaseTypes.foo }); // error
const c = processData({ data: "hahaha", type: BaseTypes.bar }); // "hahaha"
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mxoXZN)

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer @linda-paiste! Appreciated! However it breaks the validation if we use object as a data value typescript type BaseSet = Base<{text: string}, BaseTypes.foo> | Base<string, BaseTypes.bar>; processData({ data: {text: 'test', foo: 2}, type: BaseTypes.foo }); // this should give an error  [Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w8vvAm)